# C#: find objects within array with same id and sum their quantity values. Add those to the new object

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have an array or list of objects returned from the Database. Let's take this as an example:
this is the class:

```
public class products
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; } 
    public long id{ get; set; }        
}



  List<Product> prod = new List<Product>()
prod = (call to the DB to get data back...)
```

array is returned with object of products

What I need is to loop through this array and add up the quantities for the same ids. Meaning, add up 2+7 for id 3 and add that data to another object so that new object would have something like: total: 9, id: 3
then same again for id 5, total: 7, id: 5
and so on.

I am at a loss of the right way to do this. I was looking at Linq but the only way I used it is by providing specific values. Please help me with this
`

```
foreach (var p in prod){ Now what do i do?}
```

`

Comment: Why is it a JSON if it's a C# object? Just curious if the format is important here??

Comment: not important at all. just for visual just think of it as an array of products that has name, quantity and id

Comment: Are you deserializing to classes or are you using `Json.Linq`? Anyway, you can `GroupBy()` by `[products].Id` and sum the elements of each grouping.

Comment: @Coder You need `Dictionary<int, int> quntityById` Then `if (!quntityById.ContainsKey(l.id)) { quntityById[l.id] = l.quantity} else {quntityById[l.id] += l.quantity}`

Comment: @coder Is this valid json? I am curious to see C# model and how you are reading from DB into that model.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: What is your expected output. You just wanted to see id and total quantity or more details?

Comment: just those 2 parameters. Don't need anything else

Comment: @coder please check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with GroupBy and Sum (Both use System.Linq):

```
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product(){Id = 1, Cost = 20.0M },
        new Product(){Id = 1, Cost = 30.0M },
        new Product(){Id = 2, Cost = 20.0M },
        new Product(){Id = 3, Cost = 20.0M },
        new Product(){Id = 3, Cost = 5.0M }
    };

    products.GroupBy(g => g.Id).ToList().ForEach(e => 
    {
            Console.WriteLine($"Total: {
               e.Sum(s => s.Cost)} for {e.Key}");
    });
```

### Edit

With the new information provided: You can do this to a concrete class:

```
public class Product
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int quantity { get; set; } 
   public long id{ get; set; }        
}

List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
var products = (call to the DB to get data back...).GroupBy(g => g.Id).ToList().ForEach(e => 
    {
       products.Add(new Product() 
       {
          Id = e.Key,
          Quantity = e.Sum(s => s.Quantity)
       })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your code snippet, prod is single product of type products.
So, assuming your code which invokes database call returns prod list something like below:

```
List<products> prod = new List<products>(); 
prod = _productRepository.GetProductData(prodId);
```

You can use linq GroupBy (please include System.Linq to use GroupBy linq extension method) to find the total quantity of each product like below:

```
var anonymousList = prod.GroupBy(p => p.id).Select(g => new {id = g.Key, totalQuantity = g.Sum(p => p.quantity)}).ToList()
```

The above returns anonymous list of objects where each object contains id and totalQuantity.

If you are interested in dictionary of product id vs totalQuantity, then use something like below:

```
Dictionary<long, int> dictionary = prod.GroupBy(p => p.id).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Sum(p => p.quantity));
```

**UPDATE** based on comments discussion:
You can invoke GroupBy on prod without verifying the count. No exception will be thrown.

Comment: I think this is what i need. Is there a way to make this anonymousList global? I am calling it inside the if prod != null... and then i have to use it after another call to the DB and of course it won't be recognized outside the if statement

Comment: could you show me your db call - `prod = (call to the DB to get data back...)`? instead of if statement, you could combine database call with group by so no if statements involved.

Comment: List<products> prod = new List<products>();
prod = _productRepository.GetProductData(prodId);
if(prod.Count()>0){  your piece of code goes in here  }

then i have another DB call to get something else from DB and if that is not empty i have to loop through the object we put together

Comment: @coder if you want the anonymous object to be "global" then don't use an anonymous object. Replace ` g => new { ... } ` with ` g => new MyClass() { ... } `

Comment: @coder You don't if condition check. You can just call `List<products> prod = new List<products>(); prod = _productRepository.GetProductData(prodId);var anonymousList = prod.GroupBy(....`. You could follow Austin T French suggestion by defining a new model to hold the result of groupBy instead of anonymous object.

Comment: ok i will try all of these options and let you know what worked for me. Thanks